# How to clean up git repository for open source release

Tags: git

I plan to release the code of a HoloLens application to GitHub. I developed it at university and am allowed to make it public since august 2019. I was hired to further develop it. Unfortunately I kept developing in the same repository after this. All commits after a specific one are thereby owned by the university and I might run into legal trouble if anything from there will land in the public repo.

How can I be sure, that everything except the master branch and after a specific commit is completely gone from a repo before pushing it on github?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4 steps:

1. Create new banch: `git branch github <COMMIT_SHA>`.
2. Checkout this banch: `git checkout github`.
3. Create github remote: `git remote add -t github github <UrlToRepo>`
4. Push new repo: `git push -u github master`

Comment: Thank you :) thats pretty much what I did. This is enough? Great :)